# How to restrict API access to limited domains names?

Tags: php, web-services, apache, api, security

I am creating RESTful web services, but I want to protect those web services and want to give access to specific domain names. I have achieved that by following code in PHP:

```
 $allowed_hosts = array("domain1.com", "domain2.com", "domain3.com");

  if (!in_array(strtolower($_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]), $allowed_hosts))
   die ("Unknown host name ". $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]);
```

I would like to know that is this the correct approach to restrict the access?

Comment: Does that actually work? How is the API used by other parties?

Comment: You want your service to only be accessed **from** specific hosts? Does this mean from people at these hosts? Or from random browsers viewing a website hosted at these hosts? Please provide more information, this is not definitively answerable as is.

Comment: as mention in question : only listed domain will have access to my restful webservices

Comment: Do you mean the domain of the connecting client? As it stands, you're reading `$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]`, which will give you the domain of **your** server, which I think isn't what you want. This approach would be useful if you are aliasing several domains to your service, and you want to see which one is being used - is that what you are doing?

Comment: yeah domain name of connecting client.if you have better option suggest me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `<Files "admin.php">
>
>       Order deny,allow
>
>       Deny from all
>
>       Allow from .*domain1\.com.*
>
>       Allow from .*domain2\.com.*
>
>   </Files>`

put this in your .htaccess file so it will proved access to the admin.php file only from domain1.com and domain2.com

Comment: write some rewrite rule there in .htacess file

Comment: thanx , and it was all about web but how to access that in mobile app as well as protect web services from other applications ?